# pandas how take max,min,mean from rows by condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, max

I am facing the following problem:
I can  do conditional column calculations,
but,
i can't use the functions min, max, mean for every row by condition

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','bob'],
        'level_1': [2, -3, 7, -4,-2],
        'level_2': [6, 5, -3, -9,2],
        'level_3': [-2, -1, 4, 6,-4],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)


def f(row):
    if (row['level_1'] < 0) & (row['level_2'] < 0):
        
        val = row['level_1'] + row['level_2']
    elif (row['level_1'] > 0) & (row['level_2'] > 0):

        val = row['level_1'] - row['level_2']

    else:
        val = row[['level_1','level_2','level_3']].max#(axis=1)

    return val

df['level_final'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

print(40*'#')

print(df)
```

can any one help me please?

Comment: can you add the output that you are expecting please?

Comment: If you use ´.max(axis=0)´ it works as expected.

Comment: in row 'nick' i waiting '5' (from -3,5,-1)

Comment: i need max from every row (axis=1) by condition

Comment: @dimzev using .max() in the else statement got me 5

Comment: you are right ...the parentheses were missing

Comment: @zaki98 thank you ...!!! give full answer to take bonus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### # Cleaner & Faster solution

Here is a cleaner way to do this (and faster) using `numpy`, than using lambda with an apply method (which is not vectorized over rows)-

```
import numpy as np

df = df.set_index('Name')       #to work with numeric features

#Your 2 conditions
c1 = (df.level_1 < 0) & (df.level_2 < 0)
c2 = (df.level_1 > 0) & (df.level_2 > 0)

#Your 3 values
v1 = df.level_1 + df.level_2    #for c1
v2 = df.level_1 - df.level_2    #for c2
v3 = df.max(1)                  #if c1 and c2 fail

#apply everything, everywhere all at once
df['val'] = np.select([c1, c2], [v1, v2], default=v3)
df = df.reset_index()

print(df)
```

```
    Name  level_1  level_2  level_3  val
0    Tom        2        6       -2   -4
1   nick       -3        5       -1    5
2  krish        7       -3        4    7
3   jack       -4       -9        6  -13
4    bob       -2        2       -4    2
```

Read more about `numpy.select` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

---

#### # Notes on your current code

> "i need max from every row (axis=1) by condition" (from your comment)

The reason your code fails is that you are misunderstanding how the `apply` method works. **When you are using an apply function over rows, you are pulling each row as a `pd.Series` object and then applying your function `f` function on that, one row at a time.**

When you use the `pd.Series.max(axis=1)` on any row series object, it throws the following error as expected -

```
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series
```

For a series object, you can't use `max.axis(1)` since it has no axis. So instead of using that or simply `max` which is the incorrect syntax for a method, just use `pd.Series.max()`. Read documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html)

```
#Your code modified
def f(row):
    if (row['level_1'] < 0) & (row['level_2'] < 0):
        val = row['level_1'] + row['level_2']
    elif (row['level_1'] > 0) & (row['level_2'] > 0):
        val = row['level_1'] - row['level_2']
    else:
        val = row[['level_1','level_2','level_3']].max() #<---
    return val

df['level_final'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
    Name  level_1  level_2  level_3  level_final
0    Tom        2        6       -2           -4
1   nick       -3        5       -1            5
2  krish        7       -3        4            7
3   jack       -4       -9        6          -13
4    bob       -2        2       -4            2
```

Comment: thank you !!
you were very detailed...!!!
I learned a lot

Comment: Glad to help anytime.